# Ranking of a user in mysql

Tags: mysql, ranking, ladder-logic

I know this has been asked and solved in the past but I couldn't exactly apply the already solved problems to mine.

What I am trying to do:

Get the global ranking of a user along with the 10 below and 10 above them and the top rankings for the top 20 users (ELO).

I have managed to get the top 20 users, but I am having issues getting a single user's ranking along with the 10 above and 10 below them in a single fast query. In addition, I am having doubts as to how fast using Rank over() is in the event that I have over 1M rows. Lastly, no players should have the same ranking even if their ELO is the same (hence the multiple order by).

Below is my table

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS elo_ladder
(
    elo_ladder_incr INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    player_id INT DEFAULT NULL,
    
    elo_rank INT DEFAULT 1000,
    elo_rank_wins INT DEFAULT 0,
    
    PRIMARY KEY (elo_ladder_incr),
    KEY elo_rank_key (elo_rank),
    KEY elo_rank_wins_key (elo_rank_wins),
    FOREIGN KEY (player_id) REFERENCES users(player_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Now the query below is the one I have for getting the top 20 users.

// Get top ranked players

```sql
  SELECT
    player_id,
    elo_rank,
    elo_rank_wins
  FROM elo_ladder
  ORDER BY 
  elo_rank DESC, 
  elo_rank_wins DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

// Get single player's ranking

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
      player_id,
      t.elo_rank,
      (RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t.elo_rank DESC, t.elo_rank_wins DESC)) AS global_rank
    FROM (
      SELECT
        player_id,
        elo_rank,
        elo_rank_wins
      FROM elo_ladder
      GROUP BY player_id
    ) AS t
) AS rt
WHERE rt.player_id = 30;
```

Lastly, I am using Mysql InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get everyone's RANK.  This will be used in a derived table (`FROM ( SELECT ... )`)
2. Build around it a SELECT with a where clause with `rank between user_rank - 10 and user_rank + 10`.

It may be better to use `ROW_NUMBER` than RANK, especially if you deal with RANK versus DENSE_RANK.

You may need to use `WITH` or a temp table and it may be beneficial to add an index.

But it is likely that dealing with "rank" over a million rows is destined to be slow.

Step 2, above, may be replaced by

```
( SELECT ... WHERE rank < user_rank ORDER BY rank DESC LIMIT 10 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT ... WHERE rank > user_rank ORDER BY rank ASC  LIMIT 10 )
```

At that point, you don't need the actual "rank", you can simply use the metric that controls the rank.

Good luck.